# Need redirect old url to new friendly url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

a need redirect

http://www.mysite.com/product.php?id_product=216

to

http://www.mysite.com/category/newProduct.html

I try to add a line in htacces

```
redirect 301 /product.php?id_product=216 http://www.mysite.com/category/newProduct.html
```

but dont work.

If I add

```
Redirect /product.php http://www.mysite.com/category/newProduct.html
```

All links like

```
http://www.mysite.com/product.php
http://www.mysite.com/product.php?id_product=216
http://www.mysite.com/product.php?id_product=219
```

Go to homepage http://www.mysite.com/

Any idea. THX

Comment: "don't work" how? .htaccess being ignored? redirecting to wrong page? not redirect at all?

Comment: when add this line, not redirect at all

Answer (score 0):

Check the following:

- Make sure your file is called `.htaccess`, not `htaccess` as you say above.
- If you're using FTP to transfer it to the server, use ASCII rather than binary transfer mode.
- Make sure the `.htaccess` file is in a directory where the Apache `AllowOverride` directory option is on if you're using apache web server.

Comment: the name of the file as you say it is .htaccess